# Failed to find file "C:\dir1\dir2\file.pdf"

Tags: bibtex

I have been at it for about an hour now and just can't solve the problem. When I try to build my document, which was OK just yesterday I get this in the messages tab of TexStudio:

```
Process started: bibtex.exe "Predloga za VSS I.st. PAP in MAG II.st. - dvostransko"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 21.12.10)
The top-level auxiliary file: Predloga za VSS I.st. PAP in MAG II.st. - dvostransko.aux
Case mismatch error between cite keys Merlo and merlo
---line 62 of file Predloga za VSS I.st. PAP in MAG II.st. - dvostransko.aux
 : \citation{Merlo
 :                }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Predloga za VSS I.st. PAP in MAG II.st. - dvostransko.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Predloga za VSS I.st. PAP in MAG II.st. - dvostransko.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
Process exited with error(s)


Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Predloga za VSS I.st. PAP in MAG II.st. - dvostransko".tex
```

Process exited with error(s)

And I get this under the part of the screen where the PDF previewer should be.

```
Failed to find file "C:\dir1\dir2\file.pdf" Perhaps it has been delted.
```

I know that this is a possible duplicate but I just can't seem to find the solution. This project is really important and it has been in the works for quite some time. I have backups but even those don't work right.

Comment: I have no idea how I managed to post twice. I have deleted that one.

Comment: Welcome. // What changed between the last time it worked for you, and the first time it failed?

Comment: Please show the LaTeX code that employs a `\cite`-like command.

Comment: "Case mismatch error between cite keys Merlo and merlo", Check how you entered Merlo in your `.bib` file. You may also try to compile the bibtex separately with `F8`.

Comment: I solved the Merlo/merlo problem, but the process still exits with 2 errors. And this is from .bib file `@article{Merlo,
     author = "Lisa E. Merlo",
     title = "Electrocoating",
     journal = "Metal Finishing",
     number = "108",
     year = "2010",
     pages = "171--175"
    }`

Comment: don't use a tool like texify to build your document if you get errors. Use pdflatex and bibtex directly to get better error messages.

Comment: I am using a template that was provided to me. Can you help me fix that

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by redownloading a template and just copying and pasting the contents of .tex file to the fresh one. Now it works. For me it is still a mystery why it stopped working. But I saved my work which is good. Made sure to create a fresh backup of the new file.